# Cordova throws syntax error when trying to add platform

Tags: ios, linux, ubuntu, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to install Cordova and Ionic Framework on a Ubuntu server. I already used Node.js on it, so simply ran:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Then I cloned a sample project from GitHub

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-weather.git
```

I entered the directory and tried to add the iOS platform library in order to build it:

```
cd ionic-weather
sudo cordova platform add ios
```

However it throws the following error:

```
Creating ios project...
/home/benedict/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: 33: /home/benedict/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Error: /home/benedict/.cordova/lib/ios/cordova/3.4.0/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:112:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

I've tried reinstalling Cordova in case something got corrupted, but no luck. I can't seem to find anyone else with this issue either so I'm kinda stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: this happens with android as well, even with ant and jdk 7 (jdk) installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This turned out to be a combination of several problems:

1. Ant is a required dependency, although it's not documented as a dependency as far as I can tell from any of the install guides the ionic guide or cordova guide point to.  In fact I found this out by digging around SO and a few other dark corners of the internet
2. JDK must also be installed. (not just JRE)
3. 2 folders have to be added to the path (for Android anyways).

### Ant

This can be installed via `sudo apt-get install ant`.

### jdk

sudo update-alternatives --config java

first, you can find out if you have jdk by running `sudo update-alternatives --get-selections | grep ^java

if you already have the jdk, you can update your jre to the jdk version using `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

if not, then install jdk (not just the jre), using `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`

### Path setting in ~/.bashrc

```
$ cd ~
$ sudo vi .bashrc
```

at the bottom, before the `PATH=` add the path to the bundle folders for both `platform-tools` folder and the `tools` folder under the `sdk` folder.  Several of the guides only mention the `platform-tools` folder.

The guide specifically mentions ios can't be installed on Windows, but strangely leaves out Linux.  This may be an oversight, but I can't be sure. There was some indication in the ionic guides that ios emulation could be done on linux, even though actual development could only be done on OSx.

**the ios platform requires xcode 4.5 with cordova, which needs OSx 10.7**  you basically can't add the ios platform tools on Windows *or* Linux. Unfortunately cordova and ionic both seem to forget Linux exists, and therefore the docs imply this will run on Linux when they note inoperability on Windows but say nothing about Linux.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that your trying to build the app on a machine that doesnt have Mac OS installed. In order to add IOS platform you need to run this command on a mac.

Check the Prerequisites here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: Your comment seemed to be totally irrelevant at first.  However in the course of researching my answer, I discovered the "relationship" of cordova and phonegap.  I initally downvoted because of this, so if you edit (may I suggest a statement about the relationship between phonegap/cordova, or perhaps their identical dependencies) I can remove my downvote.  Thanks!